# How does XPathNavigator respect relative context?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xpathnavigator

**Introduction:**

If I run an inner XPath query, I get text nodes that are not related to the context of the outer XPath query *(the previous received node)*. Does this mean that XPathNavigator always have the whole tree available so it does not respect the current context? Does it mean that query is always executed againts the root? Please see the example below:

**This is the example of book.xml:**

```
<bookstore>
  <book genre="autobiography" publicationdate="1981-03-22" ISBN="1-861003-11-0">  
    <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>  
    <author>  
      <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>  
      <last-name>Franklin</last-name>  
    </author>  
    <price>8.99</price>  
  </book>  
  <book genre="novel" publicationdate="1967-11-17" ISBN="0-201-63361-2">  
    <title>The Confidence Man</title>  
    <author>  
      <first-name>Herman</first-name>  
      <last-name>Melville</last-name>  
    </author>  
    <price>11.99</price>  
  </book>  
  <book genre="philosophy" publicationdate="1991-02-15" ISBN="1-861001-57-6">  
    <title>The Gorgias</title>  
    <author>  
      <name>Plato</name>  
    </author>  
    <price>9.99</price>  
  </book>  
</bookstore>
```

**XPath queries:**

- **/bookstore/book/title**
- **/bookstore/book/author/first-name/text()**

> I would expect that If I run the second query *(inner one)* in the context of the
> first one, I would not get any results. However I was wrong.

**Tested code:**

```
var xpath1 = "/bookstore/book/title";
var xpath2 = "/bookstore/book/author/first-name/text()";

var xDocument = new XPathDocument(new StreamReader("./book.xml"));
var navigator = xDocument.CreateNavigator();
navigator.MoveToChild(XPathNodeType.Element);
    
var iterator = navigator.Select(xpath1) as XPathNodeIterator;
while (iterator?.MoveNext() ?? false)
{
    var result = iterator.Current.Evaluate(xpath2) as XPathNodeIterator;
    while (result?.MoveNext() ?? false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result.Current.Value);
    }
}
```

**The result I got:**

The `xpath1` returns 3 nodes, resp. iterator has 3 elements because the `<title>` is obviously in the XML document for the three times. Then I would expect that subsequent query `xpath2` will return no data since I am in context of the `<title>` node. However, it seems this is not the case. And on the output I got 3x the `Benjamin Herman`.

**Question:**

> How did I get `<first-name>` text values in the results even though I ran
> the query in the context of the `<title>` node? Does it mean that
> `XPathNavigator` always performs over the entire tree?

Comment: You are using somewhat antiquated XML API. It is better to use **LINQ to XML** API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thank you for the suggestion, I know about these options or even about 3rd parties. However, I am restricted by internal policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `XPathNavigator` will not take an absolute XPath such as

```
/bookstore/book/author/first-name/text()
```

and apply it relatively.  If you want to reach `author` etc when the context node is `title`, then use

```
../author/first-name/text()
```

or

```
following-sibling::author/first-name/text()
```

Comment: In other words, if XPathNavigator contains an absolute XPath, it can execute within the entire XML tree without respecting the current context. On the other hand if there is a relative XPath it is executed regards the current context and if no result is there, null is returned. Am I correct?

Comment: @Arsiwaldi: Yes about the relative/absolute part.   [`XPathNavigator.select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.select?view=net-6.0#system-xml-xpath-xpathnavigator-select(system-string)) returns a `XPathNodeIterator`.

Comment: got it, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            var results = doc.Descendants("book")
                .Where(x => (string)x.Element("title") == "The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    author_first_name = (string)x.Descendants("first-name").FirstOrDefault(),
                    author_last_name = (string)x.Descendants("last-name").FirstOrDefault(),
                    price = (decimal)x.Element("price"),
                    genre = (string)x.Attribute("genre"),
                    publication = (DateTime)x.Attribute("publicationdate"),
                    isbn = (string)x.Attribute("ISBN")
                }).ToList();
          
        }
  
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing this alternative way.